# CSS: Fitting a wide element into a div without stretching it

Tags: css, layout, html, overflow

I'm trying to add a very wide `div` to an existing, non-fixed-size `div`. Here's a minimal example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqxEL/1/)):

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div style="float: right; border: 1px solid green;">
            Some content
            <div id="problematic-div" style="border: 1px solid red; overflow: auto;">
                This_is_a_very_long_unbreakable_string_but_I_don't_want_it_to_have_the_ability_to_stretch_the_div<br/>
                It_should_have_a_horizontal_scrollbar_instead
            </div>
            Some content here too
        </div>
        Main content goes here
    </body>
</html>
```

What happens is that the large inner `div` makes the outer `div` stretch to fit. I'd like the outer div not to resize (instead, to keep the size that it would have if the inner `div` wasn't there), and instead have the inner `div` display a horizontal scrollbar.

This is very easy to do if it's possible to know how large the outer `div` should be, and limiting the inner div's `width` to that, but here I'd like to make the outer `div`'s size criteria to be "**use whatever width would fit all inner elements, except that wide inner `div`**".

In order to do this, my guess is that the inner `div` needs to ignored from the outer one's size computations **for width only**, not for height, and that's what I'm not sure how to do. I've tried a few things:

- Setting the outer `div`'s `position` to `relative` and then setting the inner one's to `absolute`. This works to the extent that the outer `div` is no longer stretched by the inner one, but the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear, its position is at 0,0 from the top-left corner of the outer div, and it overlaps some of the outer div's content
- Making the inner `div` float, and wrapping it between two `clear: both` elements as follows, which still causes the outer element to stretch:

.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="problematic-div" style="border: 1px solid red; float: left; overflow: auto;">
    This_is_a_very_long_unbreakable_string_but_I_don't_want_it_to_have_the_ability_to_stretch_the_div<br/>
    It_should_have_a_horizontal_scrollbar_instead
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
Some content here too
```

- Some Mozilla vendor prefixes of `width` (`min-content`, `fit-content`, `available`), but none of them seemed to have the effect I want

In short, I'd like an effect much like the HTML code listing above on this very page, but this page achieves it by setting a fixed width on the question container. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: You know of `overflow:hidden` and `overflow-x:hidden` I take it? If not, try that.

Comment: @David `overflow:hidden` isn't applicable here as there is no specific width set on the container, and, as such, no overflow.

Comment: Ahh, of course. That makes sense. I understand now. Have to think about that one...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is logically incorrect. By not specifying a width for the outer div, you are effectively telling it to stretch to fit its contents.

Comment: Is this something like you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/g9pQ6/ You'll probably need to have your sidebar fixed width.

Comment: When you said you do not know the size of the outer div, did you mean that you do not know the exact size in px?  DO you know what percentage from the page it may be?  Like @FluffyKitten said without setting the size of your outer div you cannot hide or put a scroll bar for the inner content, as the div tag tends to grow to fit the inner content. If you do not know the size upfront you could be able to obtain this via JavaScript.

Comment: @xthexder This is how stackoverflow achieves it for code listings as well; I'd like to achieve this without setting a fixed width on the sidebar. @BrendanCutjar I will specify it as a percentage or an `em` multiple if I have to, as a last resort. I am trying to achieve this without specifying any size values and that is my question; if it turns out that it is impossible to solve this without specifying size values, then I will use that. @FluffyKitten In a nutshell, I'd like the div to fit to its contents, except that one wide inner div.

Comment: @EtiennePerot yes I understand that - the problem is the "except" in your requirement... you cannot limit the width of an element without somehow telling it that you want to limit it! If you don't specify a width, then the div will by default stretch to fit the contents. The only way to is to specify a width- either explicitly on the div or implicitly e.g. by setting the width of everything else like xthexder showed or setting the width of the content of the div.

Comment: Can you explain why you are so against setting a width anywhere in your page layout so we can understand what you are trying to achieve? Maybe then we can suggest a useful solution, because its impossible to impose a limit without specifying that limit

Comment: @FluffyKitten Then I guess the real answer to my question would simply be "No, this is not possible" (which I would accept as an answer~). The reason I don't want to set a width is because I'd like the sidebar to fit its contents (except that one big div) without knowing in advance exactly how wide that content will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comments, its not possible to limit a width without actually specifying that limit.
Do you have any guide for the sizing of the columns on your page, such as percentages or setting the main column width? Otherwise the page does not know how much space to allocate to each column and the appearance of your page will be unpredictable.

I gather the reason you don't want to set a width is so you can use the full available width of the screen. Therefore I suggest you use percentages e.g 30% of your side column on the right. This gives a predictable layout, and also allows you to achieve the scrollbar you require on the inner content because you have specified a limit on the outer div. e.g.

```
<div style="float: right; width:50%">
    Some content
    <div id="problematic-div" style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%;">
        This_is_a_very_long_unbreakable_string_but_I_don't_want_it_to_have_the_ability_to_stretch_the_div<br/>
        It_should_have_a_horizontal_scrollbar_instead
    </div>
    Some content here too
</div>
```

You will need to test that cross-browser but it should work in the majority of browsers)

Comment: A word of advice - there is a vast difference in screen widths these days so it is very difficult to develop a page that fits to the width of the screen and still remains usable and readable - on small devices such as phones you will not have enough space in 2 columns for content to be readable; on large screens, the lines are too long which makes them difficult to read - the optimal width for reading is considered to be 60-75 chars.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this without setting a fixed width is to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pgRd5/

Set the inner div width to 0, and force overflow to be visible.
Then on the outer div set overflow to auto, and the scroll bar will appear on the outer div.
If you want the scroll bar on the inner div then you're out of luck.

This is not the best solution in the world, so I would suggest setting your sidebar to have a max-width property such as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/akdDM/).

Comment: I'm not getting a scrollbar on anything with this code. But I agree with your suggestion of setting the width of the other column. It is impossible to set a limit on the width of an element without actually setting a limit, as the OP is trying to do!

Comment: Using Firefox 12 I get a scroll bar. This code seems to have a different effect in Google Chrome.

Comment: Found a way to build on this so that the scrollbar shows up in the right place: http://jsfiddle.net/pgRd5/1/ But indeed, it only seems to work in Firefox. +1 still for being really close

Comment: @EtiennePerot, even if you wanted to limit your clients to Firefox this is a "hack" (no offence xthexder, but I think you know that already :) ) so you cannot depend on it working in future versions of Firefox.